# xml read many values and echo them in sh

Tags: xml, shell, cgi, sh, xmllint

i have an xml VARIABLE named XML like this:

```
<m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
      <m:firmActDescr>TEXT</m:firmActDescr>
      <m:firmActKind>2</m:firmActKind>
      <m:firmActKindDescr>TEXT</m:firmActKindDescr>
      <m:firmActCode>47191000</m:firmActCode>
</m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
```

and I was echo them with the command

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $XML | grep -o -P '(?<=<m:firmActDescr>).*(?=</m:firmActDescr>)'
echo "something"
```

and i get

```
TEXT 
something
```

but now i have the same with more than one values and the xml is now like this:

```
<m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
      <m:firmActDescr>TEXT</m:firmActDescr>
      <m:firmActKind>2</m:firmActKind>
      <m:firmActKindDescr>TEXT</m:firmActKindDescr>
      <m:firmActCode>47191000</m:firmActCode>
</m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
<m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
      <m:firmActDescr>TEXT2</m:firmActDescr>
      <m:firmActKind>3</m:firmActKind>
      <m:firmActKindDescr>TEXT2</m:firmActKindDescr>
      <m:firmActCode>47191000</m:firmActCode>
</m:RgWsPublicFirmActRtUser>
```

and also TEXT3 and so on.

how i cam make my program to show:

```
TEXT1 
something
TEXT2
something 
TEXT3
something
```

and show on

i cant use the previous method any more, meaby use something like a "while" and a xml command to get the values?
thx!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is probably `xsltproc` - XSLT is perfect for processing XML:

```
printf "$XML" | xsltproc firmActDescr.xslt -
```

In the XSLT file, use `xsl:value-of` to get the value, `xsl:text` to print `something` and `<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>` to print plain text.